# how to append hex byte in front of actual binary bits

Tags: c++, winapi, binary, serial-port, hex

I am sending actual binary bits as an hex in Win32. The code is

```
int binText[32]={1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1}; //hex:  AF 1A F5 F1
char tempInt[255]={0};
for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
    sprintf(&tempInt[strlen(tempInt)], "%d", binText[i]);
}
char HexBuffer[255];
unsigned long int Number = 0;
int BinLength = strlen(tempInt);

for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
        Number += (long int)((tempInt[32 - i - 1] - 48) * pow((double)2, i));
}

    //When i send using following code it sends F1 F5 1A AF
    //serialObj.send((char *)&Number);
    //So it is changed into big endian using following code.

unsigned char c1, c2, c3, c4;
c1 = Number & 255;
c2 = (Number >> 8) & 255; //>>right shift operator
c3 = (Number >> 16) & 255;
c4 = (Number >> 24) & 255;
unsigned long int Number1= ((int)c1 << 24) + ((int)c2 << 16) + ((int)c3 << 8) + c4;

//and now following code sends AF 1A F5 F1
serialObj.send((char *)&Number1);
```

Now I have to append three hex byte 24 24 3F infront of AF 1A F5 F1. How can we append these hex byte to Number1.

The "send" function invoked by "serialObj.send()" is as below:

```
void serial::send(char data[])
{
    DWORD dwBytesWrite;
    WriteFile(serialHandle, data, 7, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of casting a pointer to a 32-bit variable to a `char *`, why not just assemble things as chars to begin with?

```
char buf[7] = { 0x24, 0x24, 0x3F };  // first three bytes are prefix
```

If you really need to convert a 32-int array of 1s and 0s to the remaining four bytes, the following loop will do it much more concisely:

```
char buf[7] = { 0x24, 0x24, 0x3F };  // first three bytes are prefix

unsigned char byte = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    byte = (byte << 1) | binText[i];

    if ( (i & 7) == 7 )
    {
        buf[ 3 + (i >> 3) ] = byte;  // The "3 +" part adds new bytes past the header
        byte = 0;
    }
}
serialObj.send(buf);
```

If, however, the string `AF 1A F5 F1` is actually fixed, then all you need is:

```
char buf[7] = { 0x24, 0x24, 0x3F, 0xAF, 0x1A, 0xF5, 0xF1 };
serialObj.send(buf);
```

Comment: my binText[] int array is not fixed. So i have to use your first option. I have 80 00 00 00 in binText[] and using your code 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 was send . It is not sending 24 24 3F at the beginning. can u plz help me .

Comment: @user3048644 : Oops, I made an editing error.  Give me a few seconds and I'll fix it.

Comment: i think i have added it ahead. can you explain little about what have you done using bitwise operation . I tried to understand but couldnot get the clear concept. it will be helpful if you explain it little... :)

Comment: The code reads the `binText[]` array, and assembles bytes bit-by-bit.  It takes each bit out of `binText[]` and inserts it into the bottom of a byte, shifting the other bits left by one.  (That's the `(byte << 1) | binText[i]`. After every 8 bits, it writes the byte out to the buffer, and clears the byte.  (That's what `if ( (i & 7) == 7 ) ...` does.)  This works as long as `binText` is a multiple of 8 bits.